Why Dynkin's Lemma needs symmetric argument
I am confused while reading the proof: Let P be a $\pi$ system and $\sigma(P) = \lambda(P)$
proof of Dynkin's Lemma
Most of the proof will have a symmetric argument that goes like this: We first fix $B \in \lambda(P)$, and construct a set $L_B = \{A\in \lambda(A)\mid A \cap B \in \lambda(P)\}$. And we can show that $L_B$ is also a $\lambda$ system that contains $P$, and therefore $\lambda(P) \subseteq L_B$. My question is why the proof cannot just end here? It seems that we have already find, for arbitrary $A, B \in \lambda(P)$, we fix $B$ and can show that $A \in L_B$ means taht $A \cap B \in \lambda(P)$ to show that $\lambda(P)$ is a $\pi$ system.
However, the proof will also build a symmetric argument by constructing: fix $A \in \lambda(P)$ and construct $L_A = \{B\in \lambda(A)\mid A \cap B \in \lambda(P)\}$ and show that $L_A$ is also a lambda system and that $\lambda(P) \subseteq L_A$? WHY do we even need this symmetric argument?

It starts with a fix $B \in \lambda(P)$ to define $L_B = {A\in \lambda(A)\mid A \cap B \in \lambda(P)}$ and prove that $L_B$ is a $\lambda$ system. However, to prove that $P \subseteq L_B$, it considers only $B \in P$. So, what you have is just: if $B \in P$, then $\lambda(P) \subseteq L_B$. So you need the "symmetric argument" constructing $L_A = {B\in \lambda(A)\mid A \cap B \in \lambda(P)}$.

I see! That solves my confusion!
